# My prompt for cloud 9 terminal disappeared?

Tags: cloud9-ide

So my prompt for my cloud 9 terminal has disappeared. The link is here:

https://c9.io/quinnliu/andromedai_com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it time, I had to wait up to a minute for the prompt to appear in the terminal (while focused in the terminal).